Is it possible to withdraw cryptocurrency directly into a hardware wallet
Is it possible to withdraw cryptocurrency directly into a hardware wallet, or does it need to be transferred through another platform like Coinbase first?

What do you mean by "withdraw", what would be the funds flow ?
But yes, generally a hardware wallet is just a box that contains the private key and is air gapped from you computer as opposed to hot wallets. It's associated to a public key, just like a hot wallet.
